# Is there any way to get Visual Studio 2010 to put comments in left-most column?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, comments

I like putting `//`'s that comment out code in the left-most column because this makes it much easier to differentiate between code that's been commented out and actual comments. Xcode does this with the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>slash</kbd> shortcut.

However, the equivalent shortcut in VS2010, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, always inserts the `//` to the left of the first character in the line. e.g.

[image]

Is there any way to get VS to act how I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following macro.  It's pretty slow if you've got a lot of lines selected for commenting, and I'm not too familiar with writing macros, so it could probably be improved a lot, but it works for me.

```
Public Module Module1
    Sub CodeBlocksComment()
        Dim start_line, end_line, temp As Integer
        Dim selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection
        selection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection

        start_line = selection.TopLine
        end_line = selection.BottomLine
        If end_line < start_line Then
            temp = start_line
            start_line = end_line
            end_line = temp
        End If

        If Not start_line = end_line And selection.BottomPoint.AtStartOfLine Then
            end_line -= 1
        End If

        DTE.UndoContext.Open("Comment Region")
        Try
            For i = start_line To end_line
                selection.GotoLine(i)
                selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstColumn)
                selection.Text = "//"
            Next
            selection.GotoLine(start_line)
            selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstColumn)
            selection.LineDown(True, end_line - start_line + 1)
        Finally
            DTE.UndoContext.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

You can then set whatever keyboard shortcut you want.  The command will be listed as `Macros.MyMacros.Module1.CodeBlocksComment`